# Gradle does not execute task

Tags: gradle

So, this is my gradle task.
I want to copy some sql-Files from src/main/sql to build/sql while filtering some data based on .properties Files.

```groovy
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens
task buildSQL(type: Copy) {
    def db_names = ['oracle', 'postgresql', 'h2']
    db_names.each{db -> 
        copy {
            from('src/main/sql') 
            include '*sql'
            def properties = new Properties()
            file('src/main/sql/' + db + '_token.properties').withInputStream{
                properties.load(it);   
            }
            filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: properties)
            rename 'vorlage', db
            into 'build/sql'
        }
    }
}
```

Basically this task works fine when I run `gradle buildSQL`.
When I run `gradle clean buildSQL` the task will not be executed.

What do I have to do so that the task "buildSQL" is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task is probably never *executed* as it doesn’t have any inputs. The only thing that runs is the `copy` method at build configuration time.

- When you only run the `buildSQL` task, then the `copy` method runs in the configuration phase and the build is done afterwards as there are no tasks with inputs.
- When you run `clean buildSQL`, then the `copy` method runs in the configuration phase and the build executes the `clean` task in the execution phase – which deletes the copies that were just made.

I’d suggest to read up on [Gradle’s build phases](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:build_phases) if my explanation doesn’t make sense immediately. Maybe running `gradle --console=verbose clean buildSQL` will shed some more light on what’s going on, too.

Theory aside, here’s how you could fix your configuration:

```groovy
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens
task buildSQL(type: Copy) {
    def db_names = ['oracle', 'postgresql', 'h2']
    db_names.each { db ->
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("src/main/sql/${db}_token.properties").withInputStream {
            properties.load(it)
        }
        from('src/main/sql') {
            include '*sql'
            filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: properties)
            rename 'vorlage', db
        }
    }
    into 'build/sql'
}
```

In other words, just remove [the `copy` method](https://docs.gradle.org/7.1/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#copy-groovy.lang.Closure-) but keep its `CopySpec` for the `Copy` task.

Comment: Good explanation on the (major) problem, but your solution probably won't work, as the `rename` statements will overwrite each other. The files still need to be copied three times.

Comment: Ha, indeed, thanks Lukas! I shouldn’t have rushed. I’ve fixed my answer now, too.

Answer (score 2):

@Chriki already explained the (major) problem, so I'll just add a possible solution:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

task buildSQL(type: Copy) {
    def db_names = ['oracle', 'postgresql', 'h2']
    db_names.each { db ->
        from('src/main/sql') {
            include '*sql'
            def properties = new Properties()
            file('src/main/sql/' + db + '_token.properties').withInputStream {
                properties.load(it);   
            }
            filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: properties)
            rename 'vorlage', db
        }
    }
    into 'build/sql'
}
```